# Cant delete row properly due to quotation marks

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to Delete row from sql database. Quotation mark is the problem
I tried to add perfect quotation in following query but it is not accepting it.

```
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand fac = new SqlCommand("delete from faculty where schoolName = '" + schlName , con);
 fac.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

Please check and reply with the solution.
I tried to add perfect quotation in following query but it is not accepting it.

Comment: Please google for Little Bobby Tables

Comment: Hi, this is [Mr. Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), I am the head of IT from the school `Some School'; drop table faculty; --`. Your software keeps crashing on us.

Comment: On a more serious note, you have a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in you code. See [SLaks answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12431224/80274), it fixes the attack and solves your problem at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use parameters:

```
using (var conn = ...)
using (var command = new SqlCommand("delete from faculty where schoolName = @School", con)) {
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School", schoolName);
```